# C++11 "auto" to an non C++11 compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have download the source from

http://matt.eifelle.com/2012/07/17/just-a-small-example-of-numerical-optimization-in-c/

and try to compile in g++ 4.4.6 , which don't know about auto of the follwoing source :

```
  auto optimizer = Optimization::Local::build_simplex( 
  fun,
  Optimization::Local::make_and_criteria(Optimization::Local::IterationCriterion(max_iterations),
      Optimization::Local::RelativeValueCriterion<float>(ftol)));
```

Reading the webpage , I know it is because auto is supported in C++11 , so I try to search the source what I downloaded , there is a simplex.h which has the following source code :

```
template<class Function, class Criterion>
static Simplex<typename Function::DataType, typename Function::ParameterType, Function, Criterion> build_simplex(const Function& fun, const Criterion& criterion)
{
  return Simplex<typename Function::DataType, typename Function::ParameterType, Function, Criterion>(criterion);
}
```

then I change the

```
auto optimizer
```

to

```
Simplex<typename Function::DataType, typename Function::ParameterType, Function, Criterion> optimizer
```

or to

```
Optimization::Simplex<typename Function::DataType, typename Function::ParameterType, Function, Criterion> optimizer
```

none would pass the compiler !!

I don't know much about template usage of c++ ,  except for get a c++11 compile , 
What returned datatype modification should I do for this auto ?

Update :

Thanks for kindly help, I modify to `int optimizer` and compile , I got :
`test_rosenbrock_simplex.cpp:44: error: cannot convert Optimization::Local::Simplex<float, Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Rosenbrock, Optimization::Local::AndCriteria<Optimization::Local::IterationCriterion, Optimization::Local::RelativeValueCriterion<float> > >`  to `int` in initialization

then  I change the code to :

`Optimization::Local::Simplex<float, Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Rosenbrock, Optimization::Local::AndCriteria<Optimization::Local::IterationCriterion, Optimization::Local::RelativeValueCriterion<float> > >  optimizer`

it works !!!!!

g++ -O2 -march=native  -msse2  -m64 -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG test_rosenbrock_simplex.cpp 
-I/home/usrA/tools/eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4 -o test_rosenbrock_simplex.exe

./test_rosenbrock_simplex.exe

```
-2.75  -0.5     0
2.1875 1.125     0
Starting point: 10
10
Starting value: 8181
Best point: 1
1
Best value: 5.68434e-14
```

Comment: This makes me appreciate `auto` a bit more.

Comment: What is the *actual* error you get?  It's probably long, but it also probably holds the answer.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @RageD: He said g++ 4.4.6

Comment: @Rapptz what, you don't find `Optimization::Local::Simplex<float, Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Rosenbrock, Optimization::Local::AndCriteria<Optimization::Local::IterationCriterion, Optimization::Local::RelativeValueCriterion<float> > > optimizer` to be illuminating?  Alas, poor `Rosenbrock`, I knew him well...

Comment: Did you try compiling with -std=gnu++0x?

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to substitute in the actual template arguments, merely the declared return type doesn't cut it.

As Drew mentioned in a comment, you can convince the compiler to tell you this.

Simply write

```
int optimizer = .....;
```

and inspect the resulting error.

Comment: Thank you , I have update my post for the solution , your kindly information solve my problem !!

Answer (score 1):

Boost has a macro that implements a c++11 auto lookalike. It's called [`BOOST_AUTO`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto).

It would look like:

```
BOOST_AUTO(optimizer, Optimization::Local::build_simplex(
    fun,
    Optimization::Local::make_and_criteria(Optimization::Local::IterationCriterion(max_iterations),
    Optimization::Local::RelativeValueCriterion<float>(ftol)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, either you use the Boost macro, or you write the full type yourself. I'm sorry I didn't put everything, but I would code this only with a C++11 compiler. Otherwise, stick with non-template code.
(I'm the blog author).